# Difference between a cyclic and a left-recursive context-free grammar?

Tags: fl.formal-languages, grammars, context-free, recursion

I am currently reading a paper indicating that a cyclic CFG and a left-recursive CFG are different things:

> The original purpose of the LC transform is to allow
>   simulation of left-corner parsing by top-down parsing,
>   but it also eliminates left recursion from any noncyclic
>   CFG.
>   (from page 5 of http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/68869/naacl2k-proc-rev.pdf)

Note the second part of this quote:

> it also eliminates left recursion from any noncyclic
>   CFG.

I though that a cyclic grammar and a left-recursive grammar go hand in hand? What's the difference?

Thanks for any hint on this!

Answer (score 5):

A context-free grammar is *cyclic* if there exists a non-terminal $A$ and a derivation in one or more steps $A\Rightarrow^+ A$.  It is *left-recursive* if there exists a non-terminal $A$, a mixed sequence of terminals and non-terminals $\gamma$, and a derivation in one or more steps $A\Rightarrow^+ A\gamma$.

Hence cyclic implies left-recursive, but the converse does not hold.  Note that a cyclic grammar can have infinitely many parses for a single terminal string---that might be problematic---, while there is little interest in having cycles in the applications I know (natural language processing and programming languages syntax), thus they are usually removed.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Do you have a trustworthy source for that? I was told by others and have meanwhile seen it mentioned on Wikipedia, but I could need some "real" reference for a paper. Thanks :-) Edit: Harrison'sIntroduction to Formal Language Theory has a definition of it (or more precisely of cycle-free, which is simply the negotiation)